# I installed an egg with pip, but Python says it's missing

Tags: python, oauth, pip, blogger, egg

I have installed an egg with "pip install pypandoc", unfortinately python always throws an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easyblogger", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3074, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3060, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3087, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 645, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 946, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 833, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pypandoc' distribution was not found and is required by EasyBlogger
```

What can I do to use this easyblogger python script, which requires the pypandoc egg?

Comment: Could you look at your python path:

    import sys
    print sys.path

and from there determine if it's looking in the right location for your egg? Also, if you run python in verbose mode (python -v) you can see where it is looking for your files. With this information you should be able to determine what's going on.

Comment: I would also try `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`

Comment: Do these two and see if the results match: `pip --version` and `python --version`.

Comment: I am getting this, when printing sys.path : http://pastebin.com/rZBmgyxc
I have both python 2.7 and pyhton 3.4 installed, isn't it a problem?